# Method working when data is static and filed when data is getting from promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have a scenario like I  need to get some data from api request and based on that show images on the screen.

```
 return Class.extend({

      loadData: function (callbacks) {
        callbacks.onSuccess(
          [
            {
              "id":"1",
              "title":"Apple",
              "img" : "static/img/fruit/apple.png"
            },
            {
              "id":"2",
              "title":"Banana",
              "img" : "static/img/fruit/banana.png"
            },
            {
              "id":"3",
              "title":"Grapes",
              "img" : "static/img/fruit/grapes.png"
            },
            {
              "id":"4",
              "title":"Orange",
              "img" : "static/img/fruit/orange.png"
            },
            {
              "id":"5",
              "title":"Peach",
              "img" : "static/img/fruit/peach.png"
            },
            {
              "id":"6",
              "title":"Pear",
              "img" : "static/img/fruit/pear.png"
            }
          ]

        );
      }
    });
```

When I use the above code it works perfectly, But I need data from api so  I have implemented a method to get data and I have created a promise also, But this one is not working

```
 return Class.extend({
      // You will probably want to do something more useful then returning static data
      loadData: function (callbacks) {
        callbacks.onSuccess(
          evtBind().then(function (res) {
            console.log("res", res); 
            return res; 
          })
        );
      }
    });

function evtBind() {

  var device = RuntimeContext.getDevice();
  var get = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      // do a thing, possibly async, then…

      device.executeCrossDomainGet('http://localhost:3000/result', {
        onSuccess: function (responseObject) {

          resolve(responseObject);

        },
        onError: function (response) {
          reject(response);
        }
      });
    });
  };
  return get();

}
```

My code looks like the above one. Can someone help me to resolve this .

Comment: Is `console.log("res", res` being logged with what you expect?

Comment: @DominicTobias yes i am getting the result in that console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting the correct array in `res`, then why don't you call your `onSuccess` with the array? At the moment you're passing a promise to `onSuccess` so the code there would have to be adjusted if you did that.

```
loadData: function (callbacks) {
  evtBind().then(callbacks.onSuccess);
}
```

Which is short for:

```
loadData: function (callbacks) {
  evtBind().then(res => callbacks.onSuccess(res));
}
```